# Реализация покупки товара с сайта

Tags: php, node.js

Будьте добры подсказать. Я хочу реализовать покупку товара с сайта,но не знаю как конкретно это делается. Яб хотел попросить,скинуть мне конкретные материалы для изучения этого дела. Банально → Человек покупает товар и сразу скачивается к примеру → '.zip'.

Comment: А в чем проблема? У вас скорее всего есть список товаров где-то в бд, вы просто отмечате товар как проданный и пользователя, которому продали (если нужно что-то такое) и выдаете архив. Если это обычный сайт, то можно реализовать как file_get_contents('путь к файлу') и затем записать данные в php://output с нужным header, чтобы браузер понял, что вы отдаете файл.

Comment: Ага. Благодарочка <3